# Create common SQL operations in Java?

Tags: javascript, java

Is there a way of creating a sheet cheat in the form of an array of Strings in Java?

This array will hold all the queries to be executed later on, for **CRUD** operations.

> I know in javascript we can do this :

```
export default queryArray = {
   "INSERT" : "INSERT INTO TABLE (id,name,age) VALUES (NULL,"alex",23)",
   "SELECT" : "SELECT * FROM TABLE"
  }
```

And then We can use it like so:

> queryArray["INSERT"]...

***Is this achievable in Java?***

Comment: You may use a map for this. In case you want to preserve the order, go for LinkedHashMap

Comment: Yes, use a Java Map collection.  But I can't help LOLing DRY and software reuse. Why not use a shared module that controls all your DAO code instead?

Comment: we are going to use DAO, we just want to add the mentioned above to basically centralise, all our queries, applying the concept "write once, use everywhere", also , it will be very easy to maintain, all those queries especially when the project gets bigger and bigger.

Comment: Map is a good option. You can also use an Enum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't have something like an example from your JS snippet.

However, **Solution 1** for your question is possible to do with a `Map<Key, Value>`.
Where `Key` will be **CRUD** operation and value appropriate **SQL command**.

For convenience, I will suggest creating [enum](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/enums.html) for your **SQL keys**.
You can use [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) here. It is a typical map which has the key as enum constant.

I remind the **Solution 2** even easier, You can use just enum which will hold appropriate value per each constant.

The code will look something like:

```
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

enum SqlCommands {
    SELECT("SELECT * FROM ?"),
    INSERT("INSERT INTO ?() VALUES()"),
    UPDATE("UPDATE ? SET ?=? WHERE ?"),
    DELETE("DELETE FROM ? WHERE ?");

    private String sqlOperation;

    SqlCommands(String sqlOperation) {
        this.sqlOperation = sqlOperation;
    }

    public String getSqlOperation() {
        return sqlOperation;
    }
}

public class SqlTemplatesDemo {

    public static final EnumMap<SqlCommands, String> map = new EnumMap<>(SqlCommands.class);
    static {
        map.put(SqlCommands.SELECT, "SELECT * FROM ?");
        map.put(SqlCommands.INSERT, "INSERT INTO ?() VALUES()");
        map.put(SqlCommands.UPDATE, "UPDATE ? SET ?=? WHERE ?");
        map.put(SqlCommands.DELETE, "DELETE FROM ? WHERE ?");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Solution 1:");
        for (Map.Entry<SqlCommands, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            System.out.printf("Key: [%s] for value: [%s]\n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("\nSolution 2:");
        for (SqlCommands sqlCommand : SqlCommands.values()) {
            System.out.printf("Enum key: [%s], and value: [%s]\n", sqlCommand, sqlCommand.getSqlOperation());
        }
    }
}
```

With output:

```
Solution 1:
Key: [SELECT] for value: [SELECT * FROM ?]
Key: [INSERT] for value: [INSERT INTO ?() VALUES()]
Key: [UPDATE] for value: [UPDATE ? SET ?=? WHERE ?]
Key: [DELETE] for value: [DELETE FROM ? WHERE ?]

Solution 2:
Enum key: [SELECT], and value: [SELECT * FROM ?]
Enum key: [INSERT], and value: [INSERT INTO ?() VALUES()]
Enum key: [UPDATE], and value: [UPDATE ? SET ?=? WHERE ?]
Enum key: [DELETE], and value: [DELETE FROM ? WHERE ?]
```

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you use is a map and Java provides an implementation with the `HashMap` class. In combination with static fields you might achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of completeness, I'd like to mention that java 9+ provides a convenient way to build a map that looks similar to your js snippet:

```
static final Map<String, String> SQL_CHEAT_SHEET = Map.of(
    "INSERT", "INSERT INTO ...",
    "SELECT", "SELECT FROM ..."
);
```